# Can I create a Model from a TableConnection in PynamoDB?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, pynamodb

I have existing DynamoDB tables created through an infrastructure-as-code implementation.

Within my application I would like to use the `Model` abstraction for this existing table.

I used `TableConnection` to connect to the existing table and run the lower level commands (`get_item` etc.).

Is there a way to create a `Model` from an existing `TableConnection` (without redefining the `Model`)?

Something like this:

```
table = TableConnection('ExistingTable')
ExistingTable = Model.create_model_from_existing(table)  # made up method
new_item  = ExistingTable('hash key', 'sort key')
new_item.save()
```

Comment: I don't think that option is available.  You can re-use existing tables, but I believe you'll have to define the model manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a Model from an existing `TableConnection` (without redefining the Model)?

No unfortunately, there’s no method to do that.

You will have to create the `Model` manually.